# Rails Resque keeps running old code even after server restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, resque

I've got the resque gem running and for some reason it seems to be caching the job code. Rails in currently in the dev environment and this still persists after server restart.

I've tried changing the queue name but the same code continues to be run. 
The only thing that works is creating an entirely new class with a different name and then calling that.

Is there a cache that can be cleared?

Comment: Resque is not restarted automatically when you restart your server. Did you try to restart your Resque process?

Answer (score 1):

There are resque worker(s) process running in the background that requires you to restart them.  You need to restart your resque worker(s) in order for your changes to take effect.